# Magento Product Insert Error

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I installed magento 1.9.1 and took the tables from a magento 1.5 database.
I made all the necessary changes, I am making request normally, registering client normally, changing product normally.
However, when trying to add a new product, I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '25811-1' for key 'IDX_STOCK_PRODUCT'
```

The query was:

```
INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_item` (`product_id`, `stock_id`, `qty`, `use_config_min_qty`, `is_qty_decimal`, `backorders`, `use_config_backorders`, `use_config_min_sale_qty`, `use_config_max_sale_qty`, `is_in_stock`, `low_stock_date`, `use_config_notify_stock_qty`, `use_config_manage_stock`, `stock_status_changed_automatically`, `use_config_qty_increments`, `use_config_enable_qty_increments`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The unique changes I saw in the product tables was the column `stock_status_changed_automaticall` in magento 1.5 is called `stock_status_changed_auto` so I changed it in the new store.
Even with this change the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mysql error not a magento error.

A unique index already has a value, meaning there is a row that already exists in the table with the unique id of "25811-1". You can remove that row, or assign a new ID to any new rows you are adding into your table. In other words you cannot re-add ID "25811-1" you would need to insert at "25811-2" or whatever is not already taken.

Most likely what has happened is a new constraint was added to the table for better indexing. The only way to fix this without modifying data would be to set the mysql starting index ID to something after the last record in your table. Do not use this as i don't know how your indexes are built but something along the lines of:

```
ALTER TABLE something AUTO_INCREMENT=123456; //You might need to build this via your composite indexes
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not understand why he did not registers in the sequel. I will try to delete and see if he accepts. I realized that is truncated. The problem is that I have this product linked to sales, this will give a problem. I will try and return.